# Chrome mouse scrolling not working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first post, so hopefully people will be easy on me.

Don't know if its a viewport issue since I've had some issues with fitting the footer. Some post suggest modifying overflow, but scroll bar is available and can manually be scrolled, using the mouse wheel is the issue.

Here is link to the site..

http://d15.c40.myftpupload.com/architecture/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At least 2 parts of your JS are doing some actions on mousewheel event. Consider revisiting them and perhaps testing the page with them being commented out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the quick response. This makes sense since I just modified the footer for mobile, will update with my findings.

Comment: Oh, and these two events are registered for <body> tag. Perhaps they shouldn't.